# Django duplicated query causing slow loading

Tags: python, sql, django, web

I'm having trouble finding a solution for duplicated queries, I tried doing this.

**Code:**

```
for c in coupons:
    fname = Users.objects.filter(
        id=c['WhoReviewed']).values('first_name')
    lname = Users.objects.filter(
        id=c['WhoReviewed']).values('last_name')

    for f in fname:
        first = f['first_name']
    for l in lname:
        last = l['last_name']

        full = first + ' ' + last
        c['WhoReviewed'] = full
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: first, What do you try to do?

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco: I think the OP wants to find for each coupon with `whoReviewed` the details of the user who reviewed this.

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You here make two queries per coupon. You can fetch all the users with one query, and then determine the full names with:

```
users = Users.objects.filter(
    id__in=[c['WhoReviewed'] for c in coupons]
)
temp = {}
for user in users:
    temp[user.id] = f'{user.first_name} {user.last_name}'

for c in coupons:
    data = temp.get(int(c['WhoReviewed']))
    if data is not None:
        c['WhoReviewed'] = data
```

The modeling however looks a bit "odd". Normally one should expect that the `coupon` model (?) has a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model to point to the person who reviewed the coupon. You can then use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to piggyback on the query for the coupons to immediately load the related users as well.